# What is the Java EE framework for web services?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I would like to build a server with web services using Java EE, but I don't know which is the best Java EE framework.

Important to me are interoperability, performance, security and changeability.

P.s.

My server will not be used for a website, but it will be used to distribute applications (for mobile).

Comment: thanks for your answer! But I wonder between spring web services and apache axis2. I don't know what is better. Can you give me more information about 2 frameworks. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: J2EE or Java EE? It makes a huge differnece. The JAX-WS (or even JAX-RS) which would be an excellent answer doesn't exist in the vintage J2EE.

Comment: J2EE I have to build server on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAX-WS, JAX-RS, JAXB

Comment: Its a jsr but no less powerful than any third party framewrok, it simplifies both web service creation and invocation a lot. moreover it is supported any j2ee compliant engine hence making your services prortable to any engine. you can as well given a wsdl generate both client proxies and implementation skeletons using tools like eclipse, netbeans etc.

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous java API for the web services. The varies depends on the data handling formats;
1. SOAP 
2. RESTful web services, which is commonly used i.e. JAX-WS and JAX-RS

But mostly used web service is Restful...